# Obtener la url anterior de una single page app

Tags: javascript, html

necesito realizar algo segun la direccion la url de de donde procedí,
pero de una single page app, que maneja las urls de esta manera:

```
https://mypage.com/checkout/#/profile
https://mypage.com/checkout/#/email
https://mypage.com/checkout/#/shipping
```

necesito que por ejemplo estando en `https://mypage.com/checkout/#/shipping`
si la pagina desde la que llegue alli fue `https://mypage.com/checkout/#/profile`
realizar algo

Intenté usando document.referrer pero me devuelve solo la url de la pagina,

> window.location.hash

Si me devuelve el hash de la pagina actual, hay alguna forma de acceder al de la pagina anterior?

Comment: probaste guardarlo en localStorage? como por ej, localStorage.setItem('prevURL', 'HTTPS:.....'?
Lo actualizar al cambiar de URL y lo cargas, y trabajas segun el resultado

Answer (score 0):

ya intentaste usa el siguiente método

El history.back()método carga la URL (página) anterior en la lista del historial.

El history.back()método solo funciona si existe una página anterior.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back

```
 <script>
 // me funciona bien en vue y angula siempre y cuando se usa el route de la aplicación 
    window.history.back(); 
    </script>
```

mientras que el siguiente metodo location.hash

La  propiedad location.hash devuelve una cadena que contiene un '#'seguido del identificador de fragmento de la URL: la ID en la página a la que la URL intenta dirigirse.

https://mypage.com/checkout/#/profile

https://mypage.com/checkout/#/email

https://mypage.com/checkout/#/shipping

lo que solo retorna son: profile,email,shipping,

segun la observacion del comentario puede usar el metodo history.pushState()

En un documento HTML, el método **`history.pushState()`** anexa un registro en la sesión de historial del navegador.

```
const state = {page_id: 1, user_id: 5};
const title = "";
const url = "https://mypage.com/checkout/#/email";

history.pushState(state, title, url);
```

en los link que va a anexa en la pagina web deber llamar la siguiente función o , segun lo que entiendo

Comment: El método si funciona, pero me devuelve a la página anterior, yo solo necesito traer el hash de la página anterior, para verificar que si es uno específico hacer algo, no quiero que me devuelva a la página anterior.